# What is the legal age for drinking alcohol in Germany?

Tags: criminal-law, european-union, germany, alcohol

I heard that in Germany you can buy low alcoholic drinks from 16 years old, and from 18 years old you can buy strong alcoholic drinks.
What about drinking?
If I buy for 14 year old alcohol. Will this be a violation of the law? What about 16 years?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @animuson slightly different focus: it asks if "making available to" is against the law, not the actual law.

Comment: I'm confused here. The linked answer clearly doesn't answer this question properly. (It also doesn't answer the linked question properly). It is confusing because the laws it quotes only apply to public places, which it doesn't mention, and doesn't mention anything about private (non-public) drinking. So why ask a new question which would be exactly the same as this one?